# How to parse HTML in C++?

Tags: c++

How would I go about parsing HTML in C++ on my Webserver Application?

Comment: Which platform ? What do you want to accomplish after the parse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libxml2` has a [HTML parser](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html). [`libxml++`](http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/) is a wrapper for `libxml2`, but I'm not sure if it exposes the `HTMLparser` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It will mainly depend on what you want to do retrieve in your webpage.
You can try boost::spirit to create your own parser. (Or a Yacc/Lex parser).

If your are looking for more simple information in the HTML page, getc may be good enough...

Answer (score 0):

Hand parsing gets messy, even for relatively trivial cases.

Have you considered a Lexer/Parser, such as Flex/Bison?  I highly recommend Antlr - and get AntlrWorks.

A picture is worth a thousand words, so this will tell you why - http://www.antlr.org/works/screenshots/editor.jpg