# Get HTML data to program(C++)

Tags: c++, html, visual-c++

Hi i would like to add some function to my app. How it is possible to get data from web page.
For example i login to webchat which is ofc https secure. And now there is some table with user replies.

How it is possible to get the table or some other html component, data to my C++ program.
Its SSLed, so we dont want to sniff http.

What should i do?

Comment: Duplicate of [Programmatically reading a web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389069/programmatically-reading-a-web-page) and [How to parse HTML in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270472/how-to-parse-html-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at [Qt's WebKit component](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtwebkit.html). It provides access to the web like a browser and you can access the elements of the retrieved page later on in your C++ code.